# Getting intermittent error java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied issue

Tags: java, oracle, database-connection

I am creating database connection pool using Hikari and it connects and create connection pool successfully on application startup. Application also works fine but then intermittently i am getting **ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied issue**

**Below are some details**

Database ->

- name : Oracle
- version : Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
  major : 19
  minor : 0

Driver ->

- name : Oracle JDBC driver
- version : 11.2.0.3.0
  major : 11
  minor : 2

**This is how i am creating datasource**

passing password as String variable. ( which is not null and not empty )

```
@Bean(name = "testDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ccb.test.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSourceAPAC() {
        logger.info("Attempting to Initialize TEST datasource");

        return DataSourceBuilder.create().password("*******").build();
    }
```

**Error logs**

```
*java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:600)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:445)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:380)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:760)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:401)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)*
```

Comment: Which JVM are you using?

Comment: I am using java 8

Comment: This could be a bug in the JVM. Please make sure you're using the latest update of Java 8.

Comment: I think your password is ignored and password is replaced by config file. Try getting properties from config file manually by @Value and remove the "@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ccb.test.datasource")". Set usename, url, driver class name etc in DataSourceBuilder. Hope it solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got resolved by upgrading Oracle JDBC driver to 12.1.0.1 version.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
<version>12.1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```